# ISO Year Week (YYYYww) date format in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking for a way to convert dates to ISO Year Week (YYYYww).

I used to use the following in Postgres. Does something similar exist for BigQuery?

```
to_char( current_date() :: DATE, 'IYYYIW' )
```

The output should have a leading 0 for weeks when applicable.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the following solution:

```
SELECT FORMAT_DATE('%G%V', DATE '2020-01-15');
```

There is more related information in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#supported_format_elements_for_date).